# Making a JButton appear when another has been clicked

Tags: java, database, jbutton

I am currently making a project for an enrolment system. I have a ViewCourses class that extends JFrame. In my frame i will have a list of buttons with course names on the left, and on the right, their will be a JTextField that has text set to it, with the course description. I have all that part down.

What i need to know is how do you make a "Enroll" JButton appear (below the Text area) when the course description appears, and is also specific to that particular course. when the user clicks on the enroll button, a JOptionPane will appear with terms and conditions, if the user clicks yes then they are sent to the payments JFrame(not important).. 
I will be using a DB which has a student table, each course will have a unique ID that needs to be saved.

How would i go about this?

Comment: Usually, a list of courses would be put in a JList or a JComboBox.  That way, the user can enroll in more than one class at a time.  You create the Enroll button when you create the GUI.  You disable the Enroll button, and enable it when one or more courses are selected.  For the database, you'll need a Student table, a Course table, ans a StudentCourse junction table.  You'll also need a Fee table and a Payment table.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc For programming i am well capable but i have little experience in databases. Thanks for clearing this up for me